# Target Unreachable, identifier 'huMBean' resolved to null

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, glassfish

Im having a problem with JSF/Bean in this project.

[image]

the error is that

```
/index.xhtml @32,73 value="#{huMBean.func.login}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'huMBean' resolved to null
```

my classes are these

```
public class Funcionarios implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "CODF")
private Integer codf;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "LOGIN")
private String login;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "SENHA")
private String senha;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "NOME")
private String nome;

public Funcionarios() {

}

public Funcionarios(Integer codf) {
    this.codf = codf;
}

public Funcionarios(Integer codf, String login, String senha) {
    this.codf = codf;
    this.login = login;
    this.senha = senha;
}

public Integer getCodf() {
    return codf;
}

public void setCodf(Integer codf) {
    this.codf = codf;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (codf != null ? codf.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are `enter code here`not set
    if (!(object instanceof Funcionarios)) {
        return false;
    }
    Funcionarios other = (Funcionarios) object;
    if ((this.codf == null && other.codf != null) || (this.codf != null &&      !this.codf.equals(other.codf))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entidades.Funcionarios[ codf=" + codf + " ]";
}

Object setParameter(String login, String login0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To      change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

bean

```
@Stateless
public class HUBean implements HUBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "SistemaHU-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param login
     * @param senha
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Funcionarios loginFuncionario(String login, String senha) {
        try {
            TypedQuery<Funcionarios> retorno = (TypedQuery<Funcionarios>) `enter code here`em.createQuery("select f from Funcionarios f where f.login = `enter code here`:login and f.senha = :senha");
            return retorno.setParameter("login", `enter code here`login).setParameter("senha", senha).getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

bean

```
@Named(value = "huMBean")
@RequestScoped
public class HuMBean {

@EJB
private HUBean hUBean;
private Funcionarios func = new Funcionarios();

/**
 * Creates a new instance of HuMBean
 */
public HuMBean() {

}

public String autenticarFuncionario() {
    hUBean.loginFuncionario(func.getLogin(), func.getSenha());
    return "logado";
}

public void setFunc(Funcionarios func) {
    this.func = func;
}

public Funcionarios getFunc() {
    return func;
}
```

And my xhtml calls this bean

```html
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>


        <h:form>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel for="login" value="Login:" />
                <p:inputText id="login" value="#{huMBean.func.login}" />

                <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha:" />
                <h:inputSecret id="senha" value="#{huMBean.func.senha}"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Enviar" icon="ui-icon-star" action="#{huMBean.autenticarFuncionario}" ajax="false">
                </p:commandButton>

            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

I changed a lot things with variables and the Beans, like to @ManagedBeans, but keep not working.

Comment: How is this  question Spring related? Are you sure the class is deployed?